# Disk usage equivalent to Disk usage in windows task manager

Tags: disk

I want to find how can I check the disk usage in linux as in windows task manager.

I mean, I don't want to find out how much free space is there on the partition or something like that, I want to find out how much is the disk used at a given moment.

Here's a gif: https://i.gyazo.com/4a91e7ed2e519d6fe628811d7c03d6c3.gif

It's used more when I open a program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question and the gif are two separate things. Based on the gif what you need is monitoring disk I/O and that can be achieved by

> iotop

you can find some examples [here](https://www.2daygeek.com/monitor-disk-io-activity-using-iotop-iostat-commands-on-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

Memory usage, CPU usage, disk I/O and many other parameters are easily laid out with [`conky`](http://conky.sourceforge.net/variables.html).

There are plenty of [samples and examples](http://desktopspotting.com/26/best-conky-configs-for-linux-desktop/) only a web-search away, that particular page has the scripts etc for you to download and play with.